# Extracting most recent activity/logon date

Tags: azure, powershell

I am extracting computers from our Azure portal and I am specifically looking for devices which have had no activity in over 120 days.

The issue every time I extract this info it only gives me the activity/logon of the initial registration for the device.

Some of our devices have multiple registrations as they are passed from user to user.

So when I extract the info it is not accurate.

I used the below which I thought should work but I still get the devices that have newer activity than my target date. I also see an error when I am running the script I have include that below beneath the code I have used.

Could someone assist I feel I am close.

```
clear-host

$maxDate = Get-Date '6/1/19'

#Create a hash table to remove dupes
$set = @{}

#create our final array
$cleanSet = @()

#load data
$data = Get-MsolDevice -All | select-object -Property ObjectID, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp, DisplayName

#for each item in the pipeline, add it to our hash table
foreach($_ in $data) {

    #if the item isn't in the hash table, add it
    if(!$set.Contains($_.ObjectID)) {
        $set.Add($_.ObjectID, $_)
    }
    else {
        #if we have a more recent date for the item, update the date so we only have the most recent one
        if((Get-Date $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp) -gt (Get-Date $set[$_.ObjectId].ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp)) {
            $set[$_.ObjectID].ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp = $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp
        }
    }
}

#now that we have the most recent date for each item, remove ones newer than our target date.
$set.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
    if((get-date $_.Value.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp) -lt $maxDate) {
        $cleanSet +=  $_.Value
    }
}

$cleanSet | select-object -Property ObjectID, DisplayName | export-csv "C:\Users\tesyuser\Desktop\Project Work\Stale machine on Azure\Exported CSV\2HIE-Stale-Device-List.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

error

> Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception
>   setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"." At
>   line:29 char:18

Comment: _"for each item in the pipeline"_, but you dont use the pipeline.. Do `$data | ForEach-Object {..}` instead of `foreach($_ in $data) {..}`. The `$_` is an automatic variable and you cannot use that as if it is a variable of your own in a foreach loop.

Comment: Hi Sorry I am not sure I follow. I am relatively new to all of this

Comment: Change `foreach($_ in $data) {` to `$data | ForEach-Object {`

Answer (score 0):

Hi So my code should now look like this?

```html
$maxDate = Get-Date '6/1/19'

#Create a hash table to remove dupes
$set = @{}

#create our final array
$cleanSet = @()

#load data
$data = Get-MsolDevice -All | select-object -Property ObjectID, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp, DisplayName

#for each item in the pipeline, add it to our hash table
$data | ForEach-Object {..} {

    #if the item isn't in the hash table, add it
    if(!$set.Contains($_.ObjectID)) {
        $set.Add($_.ObjectID, $_)
    }
    else {
        #if we have a more recent date for the item, update the date so we only have the most recent one
        if((Get-Date $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp) -gt (Get-Date $set[$_.ObjectId].ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp)) {
            $set[$_.ObjectID].ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp = $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp
        }
    }
}

#now that we have the most recent date for each item, remove ones newer than our target date.
$set.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
    if((get-date $_.Value.ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp) -lt $maxDate) {
        $cleanSet +=  $_.Value
    }
}

$cleanSet | select-object -Property ObjectID, DisplayName | export-csv "C:\Users\birrelld\Desktop\Project Work\Stale machine on Azure\Exported CSV\3HIE-Stale-Device-List.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please do NOT post this as an aswer, but [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58693100/edit) your question with the updated code. Also, the dots I used in the comment `{..}` are not to be taken literally. They simply mean _the rest of your code_

Comment: Also, remove the `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->` crap, since this is PowerShell and not javascript or html

Comment: Apologies. I understand now.

Comment: Thanks Theo. Ok I have ran the code as you suggested and it outputs the file with no errors. First machine I checked has a logon date just a few days ago. So it's still producing results of machines with logon after the target date. Back to the drawing board it seems.

Comment: @Daniel-Birrell can you toss me an email? niftylettuce@gmail.com - I can't find your email address anywhere